# autogen.sh failed while installing flex-2.5.39

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to install Flex as a pattern scanner, I read in the README file to execute the script ./autogen.sh 
This script calls the various tools needed to get flex ready
then to use
./configure, make, and make INSTALL
but it gives me this error:
./autogen.sh: 32: ./autogen.sh: autoreconf: not found

Comment: Does your system have the `autoconf` package installed?

Comment: root@hisham-HP-Compaq-Elite-8300-SFF:/etc# apt-get install autoconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package autoconf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: AFAIK the autoconf package should still be available in 14.04: see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/autoconf). But do you really need to build flex from source? The binary package for [flex-2.5.35](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/flex) is also available in the repository.